# Problema ao criar projeto no Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Quando adiciono as dependências que o firebase solicita para criar o arquivo e dou Sync Project, ele me apresenta o erro
"Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.0"[image: Build.Graddle:project]

[image: build.graddle:app]

[image: erro apresentado]

Comment: Versões correta: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google

Comment: Não entendo o que está acontecendo. Eu crio o projeto, todo default, mas quando adiciono a linha "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'"

Comment: ele me apresenta esse erro de versões. O que eu deveria mudar para compilar??